# Why doesn't this CSS transition complete it's move hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have this button that does a transition on hover. But somehow it does not complete its transition sometimes. It goes halfway and then stops or gets stuck there. How can I make it force to do its transition completely once it is hovered?

```css
div.shuffle {
  background-image: url(https://goo.gl/PydgT2);
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div.shuffle:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shuffle" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
```

Any idea to fix it?

---

Here is an example: notice how the transition kind of stuck in the half way. I realised that it only happens when it is already hovered and the cursor is moving.

[image]

Comment: works fine in the stack snippet demo. Are you seeing same problem here also?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment. Yes it does have the problem here as well. try to move the cursor while its however, and you'll see the icon stuck in the middle for a second then it moves back to the normal position.

Comment: @TheGuy Try decreasing the duration to `0.1s`. Also do you need a transition duration for transition to be visible? check out the behavior without duration if its fine. You could update `div.shuffle` css property with `transform : initial;` to get div back to its initial state.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I tried to add, `webkit-transform-origin: initial;` to the existing code, but it did not solve it. However did you mean having the `transition` and `transform` properties both together?

Comment: @charlietfl I tried it on Safary and Chrome. Both having the problem

Comment: @TheGuy: I tried on Chrome and can't see any problems. Can you add a screenshot of what you see and indicate what is expected?

Comment: @Harry I just edited my post. check the gif image please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behavior because when you use `rotateX` on an element because as the element is being rotated, its boundaries start shrinking (the boundaries don't exactly shrink but its projection on a canvas, which is what we see as output, shrinks). Because of this, when you keep moving the mouse, there are times when the mouse will actually be outside the current boundaries of the element. I've added a border to the element in the below snippet for you to see what is happening.

You don't see the problem when the mouse is static because the UA triggers the hover-in/out events only when the mouse is moved. It doesn't trigger the events when the element's boundaries change because then it would get a lot of overhead.

```css
div.shuffle {
  background-image: url(https://goo.gl/PydgT2);
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

div.shuffle:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shuffle" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
```

---

The solution is actually to put the `hover` selector on an element which is not getting rotated. You can either use a separate wrapper element or move the `background-image` to a pseudo-element.

**Note:** Even here if you move the mouse in and out of the `div` quickly, the same effect would happen because once you hover out, the selector is no longer applicable and so the element would transition back to its normal state.

```css
div.shuffle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div.shuffle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://goo.gl/PydgT2);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div.shuffle:hover:after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shuffle" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
```